# C# MessageBox link opens several times by F1 shortcut

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, messagebox

I have a Help menu in my C# application, which contains a "Filtering" item. This item displays a default MessageBox with an explanation, and the buttons are OK and Help which opens a link in MSDN.

```
string link = "http:...";
MessageBox.Show("explanation...", "Filtering", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 0, link);
```

Opening the message through the item and opening the link through the 'Help' button works OK.
The problem:
I added a shortcut key for "Filtering" (F1). Now when I press F1 in the application, not only it opens the message box AND the link, it opens the link 2 or 3 times.
The behavior is such:

- Clicking the item still works fine.
- Pressing F1 when first opened the application - the link opens automatically 3 times (3 tabs of the same page).
- Pressing F1 next time (after closing the message box) - the link opens automatically 2 times.

The problem is about using F1 because it's also the key to the Help button in the box, but it still doesn't explain why the key event occurs also in the box that just opened, and why the link opens 2 or 3 times. What I checked:

- The message box opens one time.
- The code that creates and opens the message box runs one time - when I press down the F1.
- Changing the shortcut key to F10 or something else prevents the problem, but I want to use the F1 as the standard Help shortcut.

Can anyone think of a way to solve this? I'd have no problem even if the link opened one time only.

Comment: Please show your handler code for the F1 key event. Right now you're making us guess the issue. But, do make sure that you are canceling the event after you handle it to prevent it from bubbling to other handlers.

Comment: @PaulSasik 'this.FilteringToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F1;' and it goes to the click handler with the code I posted.

Comment: event handlers for key events fire several times if you hold it down for a long period of time.. this is determined by your drivers and keyboard settings in windows, but if you hold "f" for a while "fffffffffffffffff" will appear.. It's the same thing with the F1 key.
Your easiest choice for a fix is to make the event handler "block" program execution until the MessageBox is closed. Second to that is to throttle the F1 event handler method (prevent it being called more then once per second by storing the last time it was executed in a class level variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private bool isClicked = false, secondTime = false;

private void FilteringToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    isClicked = true;
    string link = "http:...";
    MessageBox.Show("explanation...", "Filtering", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 0, link);
    isClicked = false; 
}

private void ShowMsgBox()
{
    secondTime = true;
    string link = "http:...";
    MessageBox.Show("explanation...", "Filtering", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 0, link);
    secondTime = false;
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x53) //WM_HELP message
    {
        if (isClicked == false)
        {
            if (secondTime == false)
            {
                ShowMsgBox();
            }
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Remove the line:

```
this.FilteringToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.F1;
```

When you press the `F1` key, *FilteringToolStripMenuItem_Click* is called, the link is opened and then a `WM_HELP` message is generated and another link is opened. With the above code we check if `WM_HELP` message is generated when **no** message box is opened (secondTime = false and isClicked = false), and when a message box is opened through the *ToolStripMenuItem* (isClicked = true)